# Get the actual option name in Mono.Options

Tags: c#, mono, command-line-arguments

I am using `Mono.Options` to parse command line flags in a CLI application.

For convenience, many options have several aliases, e.g. `"o|opt|option"`. Furthermore, `Mono.Options` allows one to specify an option using different prefixes, e.g. `-o`,`/opt` or `--option`.

Is there a reasonable way to retrieve the actual name that was supplied for an option during / after parsing? In my case, that would be `"-o"`, `"/opt"` or `"--option"`, depending on what the user has provided in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any reasonable way to do this via `Mono.Options`' public interface. The best outcome would be to have the actual option name passed into the `Action` callback upon parsing, but it is just not there.

`Mono.Options`' option prototype parsing mechanism is also non-public.

I ended up manually parsing the prototype and searching the command line arguments for any of the option aliases combined with all possible option prefixes (`-`, `--`, and `/`):

```
public static string GetProvidedName(string flagPrototype, IEnumerable<string> commandLineArguments)
{
    IEnumerable<string> flagNames = flagPrototype
        .Split('|')
        .Select(value => value.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace(":", string.Empty))
        .SelectMany(flagName => 
            new string[] 
            {
                $"-{flagName}",
                $"--{flagName}",
                $"/{flagName}"
            });

    return commandLineArguments.First(argument => flagNames.Contains(argument));
}
```

I hope it will be useful for someone looking to solve the same problem.